# Python typehint of chunks

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a small function which generates chunks of objects and I want to add type hints for it

```
import itertools

def chunks(iterable, chunk_size=10, cls=list):
    _iter = iter(iterable)
    while True: 
        values = cls(itertools.islice(_iter, chunk_size))
        if not values:
            break
        yield values
```

This function can be used with different collections, for example:

```py
print(list(chunks(range(5), chunk_size=3)))
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]

print(list(chunks((x for x in range(5)), chunk_size=3, cls=tuple)))
# [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4)]

print(list(chunks(set(range(5)), chunk_size=3)))
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]

print(list(chunks('qwertyasdfgh', chunk_size=3, cls=sorted)))
# [['e', 'q', 'w'], ['r', 't', 'y'], ['a', 'd', 's'], ['f', 'g', 'h']]

print(list(chunks({x: x ** 2 for x in range(5)}.items(), chunk_size=3)))
# [[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4)], [(3, 9), (4, 16)]]

print(list(chunks({x: x ** 2 for x in range(5)}.items(), chunk_size=3, cls=dict)))
# [{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}, {3: 9, 4: 16}]
```

As you can see `iterable` can be any collection or generator of one type objects

`chunk_size` is just a size of one chunk

`cls` is a collection of chunk, which can be a type (list, set, dict,..) or a function returns a collection

For `iterable` and `chunk_size` add type hints is trivial, but for cls and return value is not:

```py
item = TypeVar('item')

def chunks(iterable: Iterable[item], chunk_size: int = 10, cls=list) -> Iterable[collection_of_cls[item]]:
    ...
```

How can I add type hints for this function?

Comment: ```
item = TypeVar('item')
T = TypeVar('T')
def chunks(iterable: Iterable[item], batch_size: int = 10, cls: Type[T] = list) -> Iterable[T[item]]:
```
I tried this and with callable and get error
```TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: The problem is python does not allow to use type as generic while it defined as TypeVar. Probably I should use Generic[T] or smth like this